# How to install a Leaflet Plugin

Tags: plugins, leaflet

This a very basic question,   but how do you install a leaflet plugin.   There doesn't seem to be a step by step straight-forward guide anywhere.   I tried npm,  I don't understand what that did.

Which folders go where and how are they referenced in the script?

Comment: I downloaded and extracted the 'leaflet-geosearch-develop.zip' file from github.    I ran 
npm install --save leaflet-geosearch

Then added this to the index.php file:  

    import 'leaflet-geosearch/dist/style.css'
import 'leaflet-geosearch/assets/css/leaflet.css' 
import { GeoSearchControl, OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch';

const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider();

const searchControl = new GeoSearchControl({
  provider: provider,
});    

const map = new L.Map('map');
map.addControl(searchControl);

It's not loading the plugin..